# Redirect nodejs path and set method

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/home'.....    
    res.redirect('/path', ....)
});

app.delete('/path', .....)
```

How do I redirect to this delete path? How can I set the method to DELETE?

Comment: Please reformat your code. Also consider adding an example of the behavior you wish to accomplish.

Comment: you wana delete or u wana redirect

Comment: I think it isn't possible to do client side redirection to `DELETE`. AFAIK, we can redirect to `GET` or `POST` (with help of javascript). btw, why do we want such thing. You can write separate controller that can be consumed by `/home` and `/path`